# Angular ng-options selected object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

why is this not working?

HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<select class="rp-admin-rooms-selected-select" name="teacherSelect" id="teacher"
                            ng-model="teacherSel"
                            ng-options="teacher.name for teacher in teachers "
                    >

                    </select>

{{teacherSel}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {

          $scope.teachers = [
            {name:'Facundo', id:1},
            {name:'Jorge', id:3},
            {name:'Humberto', id:5},
            {name:'David', id:7},
          ]

        $scope.teacherSel = {name:'Facundo', id:1};

}
```

I would expect to be the selected element be *Facundo*
The thing is, I know that its possible to do this via teacherSel = *id*
and ng-options="teacher.name as teacher.id"... 
But I have the object yet their, and I need the new object. not just the id.

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lngv0r9k/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael Rose got it right. Another option would be force angular to do the comparison by value using a `track by` statement, as follows:

```
ng-options="teacher.name for teacher in teachers track by teacher.ID"
```

This works in angular 1.2 and after.
Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lngv0r9k/3/.

Comment: Thank you for the answer as ng-options is pretty confusing

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the comparison for the selected entry is done via reference, not value. Since your `$scope.teacherSel` is a different object than the one inside the array - it will never be the selected one.

Therefore you need to find the selected entry inside the array and then use this as follows: `$scope.teacherSel = $scope.teachers[indexOfSelectedEntry]`.

See at the bottom of your updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lngv0r9k/1/

Answer (score 0):

On your example you dont give a teacher object to the **room.teacher** , so the ng-options cant match anything to the ng-model.
As you see on the screen below, **value=?** means that it cant find correct value to match up.

**you could try for example:**

```
$scope.room = {
        teacher: $scope.teachers[an item index];
    };
```

**OR**

```
$scope.room = {
        teacher: {
    "ID": "1",
    "name": "Adolf Ingobert",
    "short": "AD",
    "display": "Adolf I.",
    "sectionFK": "2",
    "invisible": "0"
      };
    };
```

[image]